# Can someone explain how this code snippet works, i know it finds the transpose of a list of lists but I am having a tough time finding how

Tags: python, list, dictionary, transpose

```
def transposed(lists):
   if not lists: return []
   return map(lambda *row: list(row), *lists)
```

Comment: Easier to write, but still mind-boggling alternative: `zip(*lists)`.

Comment: @delnan maybe the Z-key was broken

Comment: I think the main reason for thi `transposed()` function was to get lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2]
list2 = [3, 4, 5]
list3 = [6, 7, 8]
lists = [list1, list2, list3]
```

Then the call

```
map(lambda *row: list(row), *lists)
```

is equivalent to

```
map(lambda *row: list(row), list1, list2, list3)
```

From the [documentation of `map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), we can see it applies the given lambda function to the elements of the list in the following way:

```
f = lambda *row: list(row)
return [f(list1[0], list2[0], list3[0]),
        f(list1[1], list2[1], list3[1]),
        f(list1[2], list2[2], list3[2])]
```

The lambda function in turn just tranforms its argument list into a Python `list` object, so we end up with

```
return [[list1[0], list2[0], list3[0]],
        [list1[1], list2[1], list3[1]],
        [list1[2], list2[2], list3[2]]]
```

which is the original `lists` transposed.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `map` with a function `f` and several iterables `a, b, c, ...` returns `[f(a[0], b[0], c[0]), f(a[1], b[1, c[1], ...])` (so it essentially zips the lists and unpacks the resulting tuples for each function call). In this case, `f` takes a variable number of arguments (`*row`, which will be a tuple containing all (sequential) arguments) and joins them into a list. So it turns `[[a[0], a[1], ...], [b[0], ...], ...]` into `[[a[0], b[0], ...], [a[1], ...], ...]` - what we want.

You can use Use `[list(row) for row in itertools.izip_longest(*lists)]` as well.

Comment: The given `zip()` and `izip()` versions are not equivalent to the original `map()` version in the case that the lists have different lengths.  You would have to use `itertools.izip_longest()` to get the same result.

Comment: This is Python 2.x, and the docs say the shorter lists are padded with `None`.

Comment: @Sven: Yes, noticed that shortly after posting the comment.